Triangle Area Finding
I just would love some reassurance that I am doing this correctly!
Okay, so looking at what we know, I know that to find the area of a triangle you use bxh ÷  2. But looking at what we are given we do not know the height of the triangle.

By using Pythagorean theorem we can figure out the length of the BC.
a² + b² = c²
So we can start to fill in the numbers with what we know.
3² + b² = 5²
9 + b² = 25
-9           -9
b² = 16
√b² = √16
b = 4 (this is the length of side BC)
So I updated my diagram.

So now we can figure out the area of triangle ABC
A = bxh ÷ 2
A = 3 x 4 ÷ 2
A = 12 ÷ 2
A = 6cm squared

yes thats fine, using thales theorem first and then finding area see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem#:~:text=In%20geometry%2C%20Thales's%20theorem%20states,ABC%20is%20a%20right%20angle.

Yes, this is perfect. You understand the basic concepts behind this question which are
a) The angle opposite to the diameter in an inscribed triangle is a right angle.
b)From there, use the Pythagorean theorem to find BC and from there it's simple.
There is really no need to use a more complex theorem to solve this, be assured that you did it fine.
